# best practice to use scala immutable Queue

Tags: scala, queue

I would like to know how to use Queue in the best functional way. 
For example, I would like to dequeue elements and print them with a recursive function. 
And I would like the most beautiful function.

For example, this is a function doing what I want. But I dislike the if.

Is their a better way to use Queue ?

```
import scala.collection.immutable.Queue

def printQ[A](p:Queue[A]) {
  if(!p.isEmpty) {
    p.dequeue match { 
      case (x,xs) => 
        println(x.toString) 
        printQ(xs) 
      case _ => 
        println("End")    
    }
  }    
}

printQ(Queue(1,2,4,5))
```

Thanks for responses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Queue` doesn't have a `dequeueOption` method, which would make it somewhat nicer.  However, note that the first entry in your match is exhaustive; you cannot ever reach the `println("End")` code.  So you could improve your version:

```
def printQ[A](p: Queue[A]) {
  if (!p.isEmpty) p.dequeue match {
    case (x,xs) =>
      println(x.toString)
      printQ(xs)
  }
}
```

Of course, since this just traverses the queue in order, one can always just

```
p.foreach(println)
```

to print everything out.

Comment: Except that queues do not iterate in-order. Or they don't so necessarily, anyway.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral - Granted; the order-sameness is an undocumented feature of `immutable.Queue`.

Comment: `!p.isEmpty` can be replaced by `p.nonEmpty`. It is more elegent ;)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to test for `case _`:

```
scala> @annotation.tailrec def printQ[A](p:Queue[A]) {
     |   if(!p.isEmpty) {
     |     p.dequeue match {
     |       case (x,xs) =>
     |         println(x.toString)
     |         printQ(xs)
     |     }
     |   }
     | }
printQ: [A](p: scala.collection.immutable.Queue[A])Unit

scala> printQ(Queue(1,2,4,5))
1
2
4
5
```

Is it necessary for function to be recursive?

```
scala> for (i <- Queue(1, 2, 4, 5)) println(i)
1
2
4
5
```